# Reportbuilder show Image from Local directory

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I'm using Microsoft SSRS Reporbuilder 2012 3.0 and I'm trying to import a file from a local directory. The file is stored as C:\temp\PT31.jpg
In my report I have added an image but I can't seem to get the expression right. My datafield 'Spec' will retrieve `C:\temp\PT31.jpg` from a query but it's the first part of my expression that I need. I now have set this `="\\Fields!Spec.Value\"` as the expression and have tried many other tweaks but I can't get it right. The answer is probably really simple so if anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is impossible and that you always have to add the image to a reporting server.